# Table and IF statement

Tags: list-manipulation, procedural-programming

I want to make a table to get a nbyn matrix. However, the diagonal are divided by zero. For example:

```
n = 5;
Table[1/(Sin[i] - Sin[j]), {i, 1., n}, {j, 1, n}]
```

I can use IF statement, however, is there any more elegant way to set diagonal elements to zero or any other default value?

One solution is, if the matrix is symmetric:

```
m = Table[0,{i,1,n},{j,1,n}];
Table[m[[i,j]] = 1/(Sin[i] - Sin[j]), {i, 1., n-1}, {j, i+1, n}]
```

Comment: The last `Table` in the post should be a `Do` :)

Comment: Cheating: `Table[(1 - KroneckerDelta[i, j])/(Sin[i] - Sin[j] + KroneckerDelta[i, j]), {i, 5}, {j, 5}]`.

Comment: @MariusLadegårdMeyer Will there be some problem in performance if I use `Table`?

Comment: Probably not, but conseptually you are not making a table, you are just looping and modifying an already created table.

Comment: @J.M. That is nice! I would multiply the kronecker delta by `I` to prevent the denumerator becomes zero accidentally.

Answer (score 6):

```
Normal[SparseArray[{{i_, j_} /; j != i :> 1/(Sin[i] - Sin[j])}, {5, 
   5}]]
```

Non-zero diagonal, e.g. `Pi`:

```
Normal[SparseArray[{{i_,i_} -> Pi, {i_, j_} /; j != i :> 1/(Sin[i] - Sin[j])}, {5, 5}]]
```

Answer (score 4):

**Update:** Timings

```
ClearAll[f1, f2, f3, f4]
f1 = Block[{Power}, Power[0. | 0, -1] = #; 
    Table[1/(Sin[i] - Sin[j]), {i, 1, #2}, {j, 1, #2}]] &;
f2 = With[{v = #, n = #2}, Array[If[#1 == #2, v, 1/(Sin[#1] - Sin[#2])] &, 
      {n, n}]] &; (* Rashid's answer*)
f3 = SparseArray[{{i_, j_} /; j != i :> 
      1/(Sin[i] - Sin[j])}, {#2, #2}, #] &; (* a variant of Marius' answer *)
f4 = SparseArray[{{i_, i_} -> #, {i_, j_} /; j != i :> 
      1/(Sin[i] - Sin[j])}, {#2, #2}] &; (* Marius's answer *)

Equal @@ (#[Pi, 5] & /@ {f1, f2, f3, f4})
```

> True

```
n = 300;
{HoldForm[#], First[AbsoluteTiming[#[Pi, n]]]} & /@ {f1, f2, f3, 
   f4} // Grid
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

**Original post:**

Temporarily re-define `Power[0,-1]` as `a`:

```
Block[{Power}, Power[0.|0, -1] = a; Table[1/(Sin[i] - Sin[j]), {i, 1., 5}, {j, 1, 5}]]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thanks for the timing tests! That's a great idea. I'll definitely add that to my answers in the future.

Answer (score 4):

I would prefer to use `Array` over `SparseArray` or `Table` here, because this matrix isn't really sparse and you are indexing over consecutive integers.

For example, if you're okay with non-`If`conditional forms, I would use `Array` together with `Piecewise` as follows:

```
f[i_, j_] := Piecewise[{{0, i == j}, {1/(Sin[i] - Sin[j]), True}}];
m1 = Array[f, {5, 5}]
```

When there are only two cases though (e.g., `i==j` or `i!=j`), I would personally use an `If` statement together with `Array` like this one-liner:

```
m2 = Array[If[#1==#2, 0, 1/(Sin[#1] - Sin[#2])]&, {5, 5}]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a different approach, that seems to be very fast

```
n = 5;
u = Sin[Range[n]] // N;
(Join[1/(u[[#]] - u[[1;;# - 1]]), {a}, 1/(u[[#]] - u[[# + 1;;]])])& /@ Range[n]
```